# Repetition of password while rsync-ing files?

Tags: rsync, password, file-copy

I'm using a script to download files in two steps:

1. First, I'm downloading a file containing a list of files from a server to my host machine using `rsync`.
2. Then, I'm using `rsync` to download the actual files (quite a lot) given in the list from the server to my host computer.

The problem is that the script is asking for the password regularly i.e. it keeps on asking for the password of my account on the server. The files are downloading without any problem, so I'm guessing that the for loop is causing the issue as it is asking for the password while downloading every single file in the list from the server.

If I'm correct then what could be a possible solution so that the script will ask for the password only once? if I'm wrong then please do correct me.

**NOTE:** BTW, key based authentication is not allowed.

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync --partial -z --remove-source-files server:~/list ~/.

for i in $(cat ~/list)
do
  rsync --partial -z server:/some/location/$i ~/someplace/$i
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory sounds right to me. Each time through the for loop when you invoke `rsync`, it's reconnecting to the server and causing you to be re-prompted.

Rather than loop through the file, `~/list` using `for` you could give this list directly to `rsync` using the `--files-from=` switch.

#### Example

```
$ rsync --partial -z --files-from=/some/list server:/some/location/ ~/someplace/
```

Comment: Thanks very much. BTW one modification needed, need to use the absolute path with **--files-from** option otherwise rsync is not being able to find the location.